# Regex matching rule for URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url

I'm trying to setup a regex rule for a string in the format of: `a/{id}/b/{otherId}` that will fit exactly this word (thus will fail for `/a/1` or `a/1/b`) with no luck.

I'm switching the first part with `[A-Za-z0-9]+` but that basically match all. I cannot figure out how to create a regex from a given string in the form for `word/{id}/otherWord/{otherId}/moreWords/{moreIds}` etc.. by switching all the curly braces with a regex placeholder that will fir exactly a similar expression.

I'm new to js.

Comment: _"I'm new to js"_ - This has nothing to do with JavaScript. That's just a regular expression problem -> https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Provide 3 more  examples.

Comment: [regex101](https://regex101.com) is a great source for both learning about regular expressions and prototyping them.  You also need to consider what a valid alphabet for a path component would be.  For example, I have seen valid routes that look something like /dogs/Border%20Collie

Answer (score 0):

Are all your ids numbers? If so this (with global match) will do it:

```
([^\/]+)\/(\d+)
```

If that is not what you want, provide some examples of what should match and what should not.